# Forecasting revenue across rows using LogisticRegression

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression

I have this dataframe:

In[0]:

```
a = {
    'Company_Name': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'Revenue - 2005':[500, 130, 502],
    'Revenue - 2006': [204, 503, 103],
    'Revenue - 2007': [5493, 493, 202],
    'Revenue - 2008': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df
```

Out[0]:

```
  Company_Name  Revenue - 2005  Revenue - 2006  Revenue - 2007  Revenue - 2008
0            a             500             204            5493             NaN
1            b             130             503             493             NaN
2            c             502             103             202             NaN
```

How can I use sklearn's LogisticRegression to forecast values for the 2008 year for each company?
and then find r^2 of the overall model?

I need to get the independent variables for the prediction to iterate across the row instead of down the column, and for each company:

In[1]:

```
for x in df.iterrows():
    xs.append(x)
X = xs
y = LogisticRegression.predict(X)
y
```

out[1]:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [92], in <cell line: 21>()
     19     xs.append(x)
     20 X = xs
---> 21 y = LogisticRegression.predict(X)
     22 y

TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

Comment: can you share your coding attempt at the problem? @n3flip

Comment: @lemon i just inserted it as an edit in my original post